# A haskell program that controls the mouse

Tags: haskell, io, mouse

First the anecdote: I was playing a browser game, and though it was kind of fun, I found that "grinding" was actually very well rewarded. It was also the case that a simple mouse-clicker program could do the job for you. I then started to wonder how I could make a Haskell program that controlled the mouse. Alas, after a somewhat disappointing Google search, all I could find was people referring to GLUT and a few other modules that supported *reactions* to mouse *input* instead of giving mouse *output*.

Now the question: What Haskell packages support mouse output, and where can I learn more?

Comment: For X11, you probably can write a quick and dirty wrapper around `xdotool`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [X11](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/X11) package offers [`warpPointer`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/X11/1.6.0/doc/html/Graphics-X11-Xlib-Misc.html#v:warpPointer) for moving the mouse and [`sendEvent`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/X11/1.6.0/doc/html/Graphics-X11-Xlib-Event.html#v:sendEvent) for simulating clicks. I'm not 100% sure about how to set up an event pointer to hand off to `sendEvent`, though; it's possible that the current bindings don't include the necessary functions. Patches welcome!

Comment: Does it also allow for simulating button clicks?

Comment: @Undreren I don't think so (see the second sentence). I'll happily accept patches that add functions for accessing the fields of an event, though, which should make it possible.

Comment: I will look into this package then. Just came home from Iceland, thus the long wait for accepting your answer :)